# Syntax Error: unexpected EOF while parsing- F5 VIP creation using CSV file

Tags: python, csv, urllib2, big-ip

i am able to communicate with f5 box and creating single object called (virtual= VIP=Virtual server) with some basic profiles.

Working code:

```
from f5.bigip import ManagementRoot
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
mgmt = ManagementRoot('13.126.189.103','admin','admin')
ltm = mgmt.tm.ltm
virtuals = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals
virtual = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual
virtual1 = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual.create(name='virtual3', description = 'testnew' , destination= '172.31.5.8:80', partition='Common')
```

my requirement is , i will give input from CSV file , may be 100 VIP's.
the above syntax has to run one by one row in imported CSV file.

```
from f5.bigip import ManagementRoot
import urllib3
import csv
import sys
import os
urllib3.disable_warnings()
mgmt = ManagementRoot('13.126.189.103','admin','admin')
ltm = mgmt.tm.ltm
virtuals = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals
virtual = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual


def configureVirtuals(bigip, virtualFile):
  # These are the fields in the file. The purpose of each field is obvious. See. Input from CSV file called 'virtualFile' and each row has config
details
  # the BIG-IP iControl REST API for more information.
  fieldNames = ["name", "description", "ip", "port"]
  virtualReader = csv.DictReader(virtualFile, fieldnames=fieldNames,
                  delimiter=",")


# Create a virtual server, one per line. it will take input from CSV file by row one by one
  try: 
    for row in virtualReader: 
      myvirtual = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual.create(name=row["name"],
                  description=row["description"], 
                  destination="%s:%s" % (row["ip"], row["port"])
```

**I am getting error unexpected EOF while parsing**
i am  f5 engineer and new to python.
Building application for bulk changes.

any one please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you forgot a closing bracket. The second problem is a try block, which doesn't have `except`. If you use `try`, you have to catch an exception, otherwise you don't need `try` at all. So either don't use `try`

```
from f5.bigip import ManagementRoot
import urllib3
import csv
import sys
import os
urllib3.disable_warnings()
mgmt = ManagementRoot('13.126.189.103','admin','admin')
ltm = mgmt.tm.ltm
virtuals = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals
virtual = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual


def configureVirtuals(bigip, virtualFile):
  # These are the fields in the file. The purpose of each field is obvious. See. Input from CSV file called 'virtualFile' and each row has config details
  # the BIG-IP iControl REST API for more information.
  fieldNames = ["name", "description", "ip", "port"]
  virtualReader = csv.DictReader(virtualFile, fieldnames=fieldNames,
                  delimiter=",")


  # Create a virtual server, one per line. it will take input from CSV file by row one by one
  for row in virtualReader: 
    myvirtual = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual.create(
      name=row["name"],
      description=row["description"], 
      destination="%s:%s" % (row["ip"], row["port"])) # pay attention to brackets
```

Or catch an exception if you know which one you expect and how to handle it

```
from f5.bigip import ManagementRoot
import urllib3
import csv
import sys
import os
urllib3.disable_warnings()
mgmt = ManagementRoot('13.126.189.103','admin','admin')
ltm = mgmt.tm.ltm
virtuals = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals
virtual = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual


def configureVirtuals(bigip, virtualFile):
  # These are the fields in the file. The purpose of each field is obvious. See. Input from CSV file called 'virtualFile' and each row has config details
  # the BIG-IP iControl REST API for more information.
  fieldNames = ["name", "description", "ip", "port"]
  virtualReader = csv.DictReader(virtualFile, fieldnames=fieldNames,
                  delimiter=",")


  # Create a virtual server, one per line. it will take input from CSV file by row one by one

  try:
    for row in virtualReader: 
      myvirtual = mgmt.tm.ltm.virtuals.virtual.create(
        name=row["name"],
        description=row["description"], 
        destination="%s:%s" % (row["ip"], row["port"])) # pay attention to brackets
  except SpecificExceptionType:
    print('Print some instruction or log an error and continue the flow')
```

Comment: Thanks @ Trilliput

Comment: Can you please tell how i can print errors in last column using except function, if it showing some error, and cont to next row for configuration.

Comment: with open('pool.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
                for row in reader:
                    pool1 = mgmt.tm.ltm.pools.pool.create(name=row['pool1'], partition=row['Common'])   ## This is working fine, i am adding additional 
                    pool1.loadBalancingMode = 'least-connections-member'  ## I need to add row options for this, but not sure how,please guide?
                    pool1.update()  ## I need to add row options for this, but not sure how,please guide?